# How can I show frameset in web view

Tags: webview, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have many view in Lotus Notes. What I want to do is I want to show only two view on web. So I'm just thinking using Frameset. I have a frameset with three frame. Below here example of my frameset.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|                   [HEADER]                     |
--------------------------------------------------
| [SIDE BAR MENU] | [CONTENT]                    |
|                 |                              |
|  Draft          |                              |
|  Completed      |                              |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I try to find in Internet but not found any example on how to display frameset in web. I'm still new with lotus web so please excuse me.

Also I am upgrading my company Lotus Notes system. Our old developer using "$$ViewTemplate for [viewname]" but it only show one view. I need to display two view in web. Anyone can suggest what else can I use other than this $$ViewTemplate? Any help I appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this question is way to broad and lacks any kind of research I will try to push you in the right direction:

First: There is a frameset- design- element in designer... it simply works... just try it... Create it, put a Page or a Form in one of the frames (of course these need to be created before) and select it as default for the web (Properties of database) -> Voila

And second: you can use $$ViewTemplateDefault as a template for any view or just copy the existing one and give it another name like "$$ViewTemplate for OtherView" and it will simply work...

Best practice would not be to use framesets and classic notes web design elements but use more "modern" approaches as XPages (introduces in Domino 8.5 in 2008).

If you need to learn something totally new, then don't learn something that is outdated since more than 10 years...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand it. I will try XPages and replace it. Never know about it because I still not explore more for the web. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @TorstenLink, may I ask. I have created the frameset but I cannot find "select as default for the web". Where is supposed I select it as I can't find it. Also how should I open the frameset in the web? I try using Inspect?OpenFramesets but wrong.

Comment: Okay nevermind. I've found the solution. Thanks for you answer!